# Заполнить структуру дефолтными значениями в go

Tags: golang, метапрограммирование

Есть функция:

```
update(v interface{}, updates map[string]interface{})
```

`v` — произвольная структура (модель в БД).

Задача пройтись по всем полям и заполнить их значениями из `map[string]interface{}`. Предполагается, что `interface{}` совпадает с типом поля, которое является ключом в `map[string]interface{}`

Comment: Использовать [GORM.Update](https://gorm.io/docs/update.html#Updates-multiple-columns)

Comment: При чём тут `GORM.Update`?

Comment: Думал что для обновления БД с этой моделью. Иначе разве только [так](https://gist.github.com/harlow/d9af9f12026a15c2cf12) для каждого конкретного типа, хотя все эти обходные решения вокруг основных правил разработки, на мой взгляд, чреваты. Golang компилируемый, а не интерпретируемый язык типа PHP.

Comment: Так не пойдёт. Здесь придётся руками устанавливать конкретные типы.

Comment: Для этого есть пакет reflect. Это не связано с интерпретируемостью. Точнее связано, но косвенно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// setField sets value to a struct's field by field's value
// field is field of struct
// value is value to set to the struct
func setField(field reflect.Value, value interface{}) {
    t := field.Type()
    p := unsafe.Pointer(field.UnsafeAddr())
    v := reflect.ValueOf(value)
    reflect.NewAt(t, p).Elem().Set(v)
}


// update updates pStructure by default_ values where key is field name of pStructure, value of map is value of
// structure by concrete field. structure and pStructure are the struct and pointer to struct respectively
func update(structure interface{}, pStructure interface{}, default_ map[string]interface{}) {
    // TODO: change pointer to interface and interface to single object
    t := reflect.TypeOf(structure)
    for i := 0; i < t.NumField(); i++ {
        fName := t.Field(i).Name
        defaultValue, ok := default_[fName]
        if ok {
            value := reflect.ValueOf(pStructure).Elem()
            field := value.FieldByName(fName)
            setField(field, defaultValue)
        }
    }
}
```

Альтернативным подходом является использование [этой](https://github.com/mitchellh/mapstructure) библиотеки